# Why redis keys keep increasing with each request when using connect-redis for session management?

Tags: express, redis, sails.js

I am using [`connect-redis`](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis) v3.x to manage sessions for my sails application(uses express session).

Everything is set up [as per guide](https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session) and it's working correctly when seen on the front-end such as when I restart server the session is maintained and user is logged in.

But when I check `redis-cli` I find a key is added for each http request; 
Is this a desired behavior? This is going to be heavy on storage when system scales as there will be entry in redis for each request.

I do not understand how this work under the hood, but **I expected** that when user logs in, it will store session id and cookie info which later will be used to match authentication info; no matter how many requests user makes after login it would use the same session id and cookie info to authenticate the user. Am I wrong or I have mis-configured something?

Edit: As @japrescott pointed out, it's not a desired behavior. I am adding more info to figure out the problem.

**More observations:**

I logged incoming requests multiple times at server and I observed this

- `req.session.id` remains same for all request. It remains same even when user is logged out.

```
//req.session.id
Request#1: c_FfYp3ueX0DsGLC0WSLt
Request#2: c_FfYp3ueX0DsGLC0WSLt
```

- `req.session.cookie` and `req.cookies` give different output. For every request only thing changed in `req.session.cookie` is `expires` field

```
//req.session
Request#1 : {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":2332799997,"expires":"2019-11-22T04:51:24.325Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"messages":{"success":[],"error":[],"warning":[]},"timezone":"Asia/Calcutta","passport":{"user":"5bc9b1559e47b71da3a61d5a"}}
Request#2 : {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":2332799997,"expires":"2019-11-22T05:55:24.325Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"messages":{"success":[],"error":[],"warning":[]},"timezone":"Asia/Calcutta","passport":{"user":"5bc9b1559e47b71da3a61d5a"}}


//req.cookies
{"_ga":"GA1.1.1355665360.1522218513","_hjid":"687665e4-38a4-4355-912c-6045e67acc00","_hjIncludedInSample":"1","io":"J-5QVd1ufdDchLv7AAbA","_gid":"GA1.1.1355665360.1522218513","_gat_UA-73956964-3":"1"}
```

- On client side, cookie is set for session properly by the name `sails.sid` which seem to work properly. It's `expires` field changes at the time of login and remains same throughout the logged in session.
- When I use option `saveUninitialized: false`, redis does not store any key-value pair for the session(not even once, even not at the time of login)

The issue is **not reproducible on Firefox**. No extra entries in redis. But above **logs show same behavior as above 4 points** for even firefox.

Issue is reproducible on Chrome for different OS.

This is **how multiple entries stored in redis(showing values only) look like**

```
Saved on Request#1(login) : {\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":2332799999,\"expires\":\"2019-11-22T05:40:39.017Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"messages\":{\"success\":[],\"error\":[],\"warning\":[]},\"timezone\":\"Asia/Kolkata\",\"passport\":{\"user\":\"5bc9b1559e47b71da3a61d5a\"}}

Saved on Request#2 : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":2332800000,\"expires\":\"2019-11-22T05:57:06.225Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}"

Saved on Request#3 : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":2332800000,\"expires\":\"2019-11-22 T05:57:11.186Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}
```

And here's the complete request header received to server from client

```
//Request from Chrome
{
  "host": "localhost:3000",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36",
  "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  "referer": "http://localhost:3000/user/dashboard",
  "cookie": "_ga=GA1.1.1dsd50.15dsfs8814; _hjid=dsf665e4-sfsdd-4dfd-912c-dsfsdfsdf; _hjIncludedInSample=1; io=J-dsfsd; _gid=GA1.1.1dsfdxx.dfdfxxw064; sails.sid=s%3A0TILcXehUjhcPDykvxwopctILbBJB2pe.ts95dvdwV9nktKeCO6%2BNahMuJ3TrWb5h%2F8%2BccRiTap0",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
  "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  "dnt": "1",
}

//Request from Firefox
{
  "host": "localhost:3000",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
  "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "referer": "http://localhost:3000/user",
  "cookie": "_ga=GA1.1.1afdsfdscd42.15dsfdsfs28; _hjid=b6asdfsd6-sdfds0df-4sd2b-8sdfd-0sdfsdb99b4; sails.sid=s%3AAUruqhip_1eTZjWq4FHMAajfdFiYpN5o.xjI8R8x04IX8MGIXHCyT1xw9ErvZdsfd2MJciToUE; _gid=GA1.1.7sdfsd86.1dsfsd3207; _hjIncludedInSample=1",
  "if-none-match": "W/\"4a44-s94WDFGXnSin4kOElQeWwQ\""
}
```

Comment: yes, you should only have one entry per user per session (until it expires), so something must be wrong. It seems like you are not setting a cookie for the user or the user isn't sending it back to you. Check if you are setting the correct domain/path/expiry when setting the cookie.

Comment: Thanks @japrescott
I did check domain/path/expiry and it's ok path: '/', expiry is a future date. When I logged `req.session.id` and `req.cookies` it returns same session id and cookie for each request.

Comment: that should not be. do you have ajax requests happening when you open the page? somewhere something isn't sending the cookies.

Comment: There are are no ajax requests.
I have added more observations under Edit section, how should I go about debugging to find the root cause?